# How many directed graph exist on $K$ vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

How many directed graph exist on $K$ vertices?

My answer:

Choose any one vertex out of the $K$ possible choices, the for each of these $K$ vertices we could choice first there are a possible $K-1$ vertices that it could direct to. For each of these $K-1$ possibilites there are two choices, it either has a directed edge between it or not. Thus we can compute the number of ways to construct such a graph to be:

$$2^{k-1}k!$$

This is my thinking but I think it may not be correct although I can't seem to find whee it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $k^{2}$ potential edges in a graph on $k$ vertices. We enumerate the graphs by selecting edges from the set of $k^{2}$ pairs. The number of selections is given by:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k^{2}} \binom{k^{2}}{i} = 2^{k^{2}}$$

So there are $2^{k^{2}}$ such directed graphs.

Comment: So a vertex can direct to itself? So there is $k^2$ total edges potentially,fine . I don't understand the next part though surely for each $2$ vertices $a,b$ say there is either no edge between them an edge directed from $a$ to $b$, or an edge from $b$ to $a$. So there are 3 possible choices for each pair.  So this is something else?

Comment: Assuming we allow for loops (which we usually do in digraphs), we have the edge set $E \subseteq V \times V$. We note $|V \times V| = k^{2}$. The edge $(a, b) \neq (b, a)$, so we can treat them as independent objects. I would focus on counting the edges, not focusing on the vertices.

Comment: I get all that you write but I don't understand why exactly that particular sum works.

Comment: Do you understand why we have $k^{2}$ potential edges? Do you understand why we select a subset of them to obtain the graph? Do you understand that $\binom{k^{2}}{i}$ counts graphs on $k$ vertices with $i$ directed edges? Do you understand that I am adding up over all such selections? Help me to better help you. If you don't understand something, please specify where your gap falls.

Comment: Yes I understand why there are $k^2$ edges (each edge can connect to itself and the $k-1$ other edges so $k \cdot k=k^2$) total edges. I can understand why you would obtain a subset of them to obtain the graph (Every subset is a potential way a graph could be formed). I don't understand the next question "Do you understand that $k^2 \choose i$ counts graphs on $k^2$ vertices with $i$ directed edges?"

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{i}$ looks at a set of $n$ elements and counts the number of subsets with $i$ elements. $\binom{n}{i} = \frac{n!}{i! * (n-i)!}$. If you have not seen the binomial coefficient before, this may be where your difficulty lies.

Comment: Got it thanks pal it just clicked!

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)