# How many directed acyclic graphs (DAG) s are possible using N vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

If all the number of all the possible DAGs are K, then K can consist of

- disconnected vertices (not all connected vertices)
- from the directionality of a particular edge is counted as a new graph

**My attempt to analyze:**
Example for 2 nodes X,Y ;

1. G1 : {X,Y} ( all disconnected)
2. G2 : {X->Y}
3. G3 : {X<-Y} ( directionality changes)

But for 3 nodes X, Y, Z; there are a large number of **possible** graphs;

1. set 1: with 1 edge
2. set 2: with 2 edges
3. set 3: with 3 edges
4. set 4: with 0 edges

Likewise, the possible space is growing.

I tried, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1464539/705412) resource but when I try to cont it for 2 edges it should be (2^(2^2)), but it violates my above analysis. Maybe this solution is not applicable to my situation.

May I know any clue on how to count the number of all the possible DAGs that can be generated using N vertices incorporating the above analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [OEIS A003024](https://oeis.org/A003024). The entry has number of references, an asymptotic approximation, and the recurrence

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k2^{k(n-k)}a_{n-k}$$

with $a_0=1$, but no closed form, so it seems likely that no closed form is known.

Comment: I see, Thank you for helping! I I was wondering how to derive this, hence I tried to find the resource _R. W. Robinson, Counting labeled acyclic digraphs._, but I could not find an accessible resource. I would appreciate it if could suggest any accessible resource on this? Meanwhile, I found [this paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Random-generation-of-dags-for-graph-drawing-Melan%C3%A7on-Dutour/24d883d745f941964bc006d7e316e8b68fc7419b) which cites the same resource, but it mentioned the recurrence in a different way. So, I'm really interested in the derivation of this equation.

Comment: @SachzEMSPE: If I’m not mistaken, it can be derived from Theorem $1$ of the [paper by Rodionov](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X92901559?via%3Dihub) noted in the OEIS entry.

Comment: Thank you for the resource! It is accessible. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @SachzEMSPE: You’re welcome!

Comment: Nothing optimized, but [here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/1bd1893f01ed729185c2fc4a0dff49cd) is a Python gist implementing this counting equation (iteratively). Checked it against values in A003024 reference.